# Not able to connect to Postgres server via java application

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, unix

In one of my project, we are trying to connect to Postgres server via Java application. It gives an error when try to open connection. Stack trace is below -

```
{"timestamp":"2016-03-17T06:57:18.853Z",
"level":"ERROR",
"thread":"main",
"logger":"com.abc.messaging.status.configuration.ValidateDatabaseConfiguration",
"message":"Failed to initialize data source: \n
### Error opening session.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException\n
### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException","context":"default"}
```

While we have tried following -

1. Ping db server from application server - it's successful
2. Telnet db server and port (from app server)- it's also successful
3. We also tried a simple python script that connects to postgre server. It also connects to db successfully.
4. We then moved back to our staging server and tried to connect production db server from there. This is also done successfully.
5. We tried connecting staging db server from production app server, which also we **COULDN'T**.

We are assuming that we don't have any issue in our application. This is because, **from staging server, application can connect to both staging db and production db**. There by, it must be some application server issue or something.

> PostgreSQL version -   Production - 9.4.5     Staging - 9.4.4
>   Java version - 1.8.31

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: error states it was not able initialize the datasource - validation exception. sure your configurations are right ?

Comment: is `com.abc.messaging.status.configuration.ValidateDatabaseConfiguration`  one of your class? Don't you have a full stacktrace? Can we see the code where the NPE occurs?

Comment: Configurations doesn't seems to be an issue since we are able to connect with both db servers in staging env.